# Laravel Eloquent updateOrCreate function is not updating whole row but only one column

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with my Laravel application. I have an XML file that I need to insert row by row to the database and repeatedly update these rows. So I've decided to use the "updateOrCreate" method of the Eloquent model. But it is behaving very strangely. I looked into docs and as far as I understand syntax should be like this:

**Model**(in my case Tyre)**::updateOrCreate**(["search key  which is used for searching"=> "value of the key)"],["key1 => "valueofkey1", "key2=>"valueofkey2"...]);  if it doesn't find any entry with "search key" than it should create with both attribute arrays but if it does find than it should update with second argument array. Correct me I'm mistaken.

Here is a whole function:

```
protected function updateDatabase()
    {
        set_time_limit(150000);//I know not the best approach - XML file has 30k+ rows so it takes a little time to complete
        $xml = @new SimpleXMLElement(Storage::disk('ftp')->get("Zaklad/PopisSortimentuVlastnostiXML.xml"));
        echo '<script>'; //debug message
        echo 'console.log("Xml optained")';
        echo '</script>';
        $kategorie = [
            'Dodávkové',
            'Osobní/Offroad/SUV',
            'Moto',
            'Osobní',
            'Hliníkové',
            'Ocelové',
            'Rezervní'
        ];
        $i = 0;
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'console.log("Started parsing");';//debug message
        echo 'console.log("Length is' . count($xml->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail) . '");';
        echo '</script>';
        foreach ($xml->table1->Detail_Collection->Detail as $detail) {
            echo '<script>';//debug message
            echo 'console.log("Row number:' . $i . '")';
            echo '</script>';
            $i++;
            if (in_array($detail['Sortiment3'], $kategorie)) {
                Tyre::updateOrCreate(
                    [
                        'IDItem' => $detail['IDItem']
                    ],
                    [
                        'Farba_nápisu' => $detail['Barva_nápisu'],
                        'Dosadacia_plocha' => $detail['Dosedací_plocha'],
                        'Druh_pneu' => $detail['Druh_pneu'],
                        'Duša'  => $detail['Druh_pneu'],
                        'EAN'  => $detail['EAN'],
                        'ET' => $detail['ET'],
                        'EU_Smernica' => $detail['EU_Smernica'],
                        'Hlucnost' => $detail['Hlucnost'],
                        'IDDisk_kompletu' => $detail['IDDisk_kompletu'],
                        'IDPneu_kompletu' => $detail['IDPneu_kompletu'],
                        'IndexT' => $detail['Index'],
                        'Index__kg_' => $detail['Index__kg_'],
                        'KodDodavatele' => $detail['KodDodavatele'],
                        'Konstrukce' => $detail['Konstrukce'],
                        'KonstrukceD' => $detail['KonstrukceD'],
                        'KonstrukceN' => $detail['KonstrukceN'],
                        'MatchT' => $detail['MatchT'],
                        'MaxCenaEur' => $detail['MaxCenaEur'],
                        'MaxCenaEurDPH' => $detail['MaxCenaEurDPH'],
                        'NapravaN' => $detail['NápravaN'],
                        'NazevZbozi' => $detail['NazevZbozi'],
                        'Objem' => $detail['Objem'],
                        'Obrazek' => $detail['Obrazek'],
                        'OchranaRafku' => $detail['OchranaRafku'],
                        'Platna' => $detail['Plátna'],
                        'Pocet_dier' => $detail['Počet_děr'],
                        'Pouzitie_agro' => $detail['Použití_agro'],
                        'Povrch_úprava' => $detail['Povrch_Úprava'],
                        'PoziceM' => $detail['PoziceM'],
                        'PrilnavostNaMokru' => $detail['PrilnavostNaMokru'],
                        'Profil' => $detail['Profil'],
                        'Provoz_Moto' => $detail['Provoz_Moto'],
                        'ProvozN' => $detail['ProvozN'],
                        'PSezona' => $detail['PSezona'],
                        'PSortiment' => $detail['PSortiment'],
                        'RafekD' => $detail['RáfekD'],
                        'RafekP' => $detail['RáfekP'],
                        'Roztec' => $detail['Rozteč'],
                        'Sezona' => $detail['Sezona'],
                        'Sortiment1' => $detail['Sortiment1'],
                        'Sortiment2' => $detail['Sortiment2'],
                        'Sortiment3' => $detail['Sortiment3'],
                        'Specifikace' => $detail['Specifikace'],
                        'SpotrebaPaliva' => $detail['SpotrebaPaliva'],
                        'Strana' => $detail['Strana'],
                        'Stredova_diera' => $detail['Středová_díra'],
                        'Sirka' => $detail['Šířka'],
                        'SirkaD' => $detail['ŠířkaD'],
                        'Technologie' => $detail['Technologie'],
                        'TridaVozu' => $detail['TridaVozu'],
                        'TypP' => $detail['TypP'],
                        'Urcenie' => $detail['Určení'],
                        'Ventil' => $detail['Ventil'],
                        'Vyrobce1' => $detail['Vyrobce1'],
                        'Vyrobce2' => $detail['Vyrobce2'],
                        'Vyrobce3' => $detail['Vyrobce3'],
                        'WebPopisSK' => $detail['WebPopisSK'],
                        'Zesileni' => $detail['Zesílení'],
                        'ZnackaAuta' => $detail['ZnackaAuta'],
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
        echo "DONE";
        set_time_limit(120);
    }
```

I have no idea where I made a mistake but if I have an empty database table everything is behaving as it should but when I want to update the database only the "IDItem" column is updated to the correct value and all of the remaining columns get updated to the same value per column across the whole table.I checked values in the XML file and everything there is correct. I have no explanation why this is happening. Thank you in advance.

Comment: After the end of foreach loop. What is the output of `dd($i);`?

Comment: The output of $i is 34873... Loop is working fine I even tried to display the content of each XML row and it was correct. Only Eloquent is behaving strangely.